# Qt Creator exclude JavaScript files from compilation process

Tags: javascript, qt, qt-creator, qtquick2

I have a few JavaScript and HTML files inside the QT Quick Project that I want to exclude from the compilation process, but I want to have these files in the final executable.

When I build the project in release mode, for a few of the minified JavaScript files, QT is giving me errors, so I want to exclude these files from the build. These JS files are used from a web component running inside the QtWebEngine so it is ok if these are not compiled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Obviously, you are utilizing `Qt Quick Compiler` with release build which compiles all .qml and .js in your resources. I assume you are using `qmake` build system because Qt Creator enables quick compiler for qmake based release builds by default but for `CMake` you need to manually enable it in CMakeLists.txt (at least for now).

For qmake based build you find the answer from the [Qt Quick Compiler doc](https://doc.qt.io/QtQuickCompiler/):

> If you have .qml or .js files which should not be compiled but just
> bundled by the resource system, then you can omit them from the
> compilation by specifying the resources files that contain them in the
> QTQUICK_COMPILER_SKIPPED_RESOURCES variable in your project file, like
> below:

```
QTQUICK_COMPILER_SKIPPED_RESOURCES += bundle_only.qrc
```

Comment: Yes I am using qmake. So we need to add/define multiple `.qrc` files and list the `.qrc` files under "QTQUICK_COMPILER_SKIPPED_RESOURCES" which we don't want to compile and just include in the final build. But can we access resources between the `.qrc` files. Means, `.qml` file inside one `.qrc` accessing image defined in another `.qrc` is it possible?

Comment: Yes, it makes sense to have multiple resources, e.g. qml and images in separate qrc also to speed up re-compilation